# Can you make visual studio scaffold etc. with bootstrap 4 in .NET MVC templates?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, scaffolding

When you create a new project in vs17 (basic mvc .net web application in c#). It comes with bootstrap 3, which means all the scaffolded pages and designs are wrong since they revamped the column sizing system.

Is there any way VS can be updated so it scaffolds etc. correctly after updating a project to bootstrap v4? Or is there going to be an update at some point for this change?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same question when using a VS17 asp.net core mvc scaffold. With a little digging I was able to find a tutorial that walks you through updating bootstrap and jquery (Scroll about a third of the way down the page to the 'Upgrade Bootstrap Through Bower Package' section):

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/bootstrap-asp-net-core-mvc

Additionally, it is possible to create custom scaffolds with more modern versions of bootstrap. If you find yourself needing to update this often, it may be worth looking into that.

Comment: Hi , Brother this solution was for .net core. for asp.net mvc there is no bower folder.

Answer (score 0):

[right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639302/update-visual-studio-2017-mvc-view-scaffolding-to-bootstrap-4/54851184#54851184) you will find how to replace the template of the edit view scaffolding for Bootstrap 4