# Update Visual Studio 2017 MVC View Scaffolding to Bootstrap 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I've just updated my Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET MVC 5 application from Bootstrap v3 to v4. I'm finding when I add a new edit partial view [using scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view), it is still using the Bootstrap v3 CSS class names for the form. Is there a way to update the scaffolding to use BS v4?

**Edit**

There seems to be some confusion about what I'm talking about.

In Visual Studio 2017, in an MVC project, in Solution Explorer, right click the `Views folder > Add > View... > MVC 5 View > Click Add`.

This brings up the Add View dialog. I type my View name, choose the Edit Template and choose, for this example, `LoginVm`as the Model class. Visual Studio generates this markup. This process is called scaffolding.

```
@model Demo.ViewModels.LoginVm

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>LoginVm</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Notice the Bootstrap 3 classes in use such as `form-label` and `col-md-offset-2`. These were removed in Bootstrap 4. Similarly, if you were to create a new Layout page, it would generate a Bootstrap 3 Navbar which is invalid in Bootstrap 4.

So I'm asking if there is a way (short of writing a custom scaffolder) to update Visual Studio to stop outputting Bootstrap 3 specific markup and, ideally, output Bootstrap 4 markup instead?

Comment: Yes, I updated the Nuget package. And yes, there are a style and script bundle reference on the _Layout page.

Comment: Bootstrap updated fine, the problem is just that VS generates HTML containing Bootstrap 3 class names. E.G. the validation summary has `col-md-offset-2` instead of the newer `offset-md-2`

Comment: Hi, I have done some research about it and found that you can write your own scaffolding if you want https://forums.asp.net/t/2121406.aspx?How+can+I+create+my+own+Scaffolding+on+Visual+Studio+2017+
or 
you just have to wait an update from Microsoft https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/282680/bootstrap-v3-to-v4-aspnet-mvc-views-scaffolding-st.html

Comment: I guess by now you know that there is no such way. There is a workaround however. I run my web application. Copy any HTML that uses Bootstrap. Use online conversion from BS3 to BS4. Then deduce/infer what I should put back into Visual Studio. For `@Html.ActionLink`, it does not take dash, '-'. Be sure to use `new Dictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 1):

An update is not yet available, however to support the edit view scaffolding with Bootstrap 4 in Visual Studio 2017, You have to edit the file Edit.cs.t4 in "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView"

- Rename the file to "Edit.cs.backup.t4"
- Create a new file "Edit.cs.t4" and add the following code, this will support new Bootstrap 4 classes and form controls ([Bootstrap custom forms and controls](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#custom-forms)):

```html
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cshtml" #>
<#@ include file="Imports.include.t4" #>
@model <#= ViewDataTypeName #>
<#
// "form-control" attribute is only supported for all EditorFor() in System.Web.Mvc 5.1.0.0 or later versions, except for checkbox, which uses a div in Bootstrap
string boolType = "System.Boolean";
Version requiredMvcVersion = new Version("5.1.0.0");
bool isControlHtmlAttributesSupported = MvcVersion >= requiredMvcVersion;
// The following chained if-statement outputs the file header code and markup for a partial view, a view using a layout page, or a regular view.
if(IsPartialView) {
#>

<#
} else if(IsLayoutPageSelected) {
#>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "<#= ViewName#>";
<#
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LayoutPageFile)) {
#>
    Layout = "<#= LayoutPageFile#>";
<#
}
#>
}

<h2><#= ViewName#></h2>

<#
} else {
#>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title><#= ViewName #></title>
</head>
<body>
<#
    PushIndent("    ");
}
#>
<#
if (ReferenceScriptLibraries) {
#>
<#
    if (!IsLayoutPageSelected && IsBundleConfigPresent) {
#>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<#
    }
#>
<#
    else if (!IsLayoutPageSelected) {
#>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-<#= JQueryVersion #>.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<#
    }
#>

<#
}
#>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    
        <h4><#= ViewDataTypeShortName #></h4>
        <hr />
<# 
    if (isControlHtmlAttributesSupported) {
#>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<#        
    } else {
#>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<#      
    }
#>
<#
foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
    if (property.Scaffold && !property.IsAssociation) {
        if (property.IsPrimaryKey) {
#>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>)

<#
        } else if (!property.IsReadOnly) {
   bool isCheckbox = property.TypeName.Equals(boolType);
#>
        <div class="form-group">
<#
            if (property.IsForeignKey) {
#>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>, "<#= GetAssociationName(property) #>", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label col-lg-2" })
<#
            } else if (!isCheckbox) {   
#>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label col-lg-2" })
<#
            }
#>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
<#
            
            if (property.IsForeignKey) {
#>
<# 
            if (isControlHtmlAttributesSupported) {
#>
                @Html.DropDownList("<#= property.PropertyName #>", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
<#
            } else {
#>
                @Html.DropDownList("<#= property.PropertyName #>", String.Empty)
<#
            }
#>
<#
            } else  if (isControlHtmlAttributesSupported) {
                if (isCheckbox) {
#>
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<#
                    PushIndent("    ");
#>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "custom-control-input" } })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom-control-label" })
<#
                } else if (property.IsEnum && !property.IsEnumFlags) {
#>
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
<#
                } else {
#>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
<#
                }
            } else {
#>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>)
<#
            }
#>
<# 
            if (isControlHtmlAttributesSupported) {
#>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<#        
            } else {
#>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>)
<#      
            }
#>
<#
            if (isCheckbox && isControlHtmlAttributesSupported) {
                PopIndent();
#>
                </div>
<#
            }
#>
            </div>
        </div>

<#
        }
    }
}
#>
        <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
   </div>
  </div>
    
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<#
if(IsLayoutPageSelected && ReferenceScriptLibraries && IsBundleConfigPresent) {
#>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<#
}
#>
<#
else if(IsLayoutPageSelected && ReferenceScriptLibraries) {
#>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-<#= JQueryVersion #>.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<#
}
#>
<#
// The following code closes the tag used in the case of a view using a layout page and the body and html tags in the case of a regular view page
#>
<#
if(!IsPartialView && !IsLayoutPageSelected) {
    ClearIndent();
#>
</body>
</html>
<#
}
#>
<#@ include file="ModelMetadataFunctions.cs.include.t4" #>
```

Comment: Its seems microsoft has made there folders in code so you cannot spot easy what is mvc or not do u no where the 2019 ones are stored came acorss this when looking for the same thing.

Comment: The generators are actually here but no instructions on how to install new ones https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding

Answer (score 0):

The templates used by the scaffolding engine in VS are fixed.
They are located in your VS install dir (e.g. %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView).

So the Bootstrap 3 classes are fixed in the T4-files provided by MS (current standard is BS3 which is added by default currently when creating a new MVC web project). Just have a look at "Edit.cs.t4" in the dir mentioned above. You will find deprecated BS3 classes like "btn-default" (which is btn-secondary in BS4) in there.

You can create your own custom T4-templates if you like. The MS ref for this task would be: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates

Answer (score 0):

To fix/update the ASP .NET MVC 5 project navbar to Bootstrap 4 you have to update your code manually as follows:

- Views -> Shared -> _Layout.cshtml.

```js
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
          <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
          <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
      </ul>
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Then if you don’t use the Login partial, you can remove it. Otherwise, change the _LoginPartial.cshtml to:

```js
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
  {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage", @class = "nav-link" })
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
  </ul>
  }
}
else
{
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", @class = "nav-link" })</li>
    <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "nav-link" })</li>
  </ul>
}
```

And last just remove the next lines from Content/Site.css:

```css
/*delete this*/
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: while this fixes the navbar, if i resize the web to smaller, the navbar turns into that hamburger icon, but when i press the button, no dropdown (i updated the project's bs to 5.1 because the bs i am using is version 5.1)