# How to Update ASP.MVC scaffoldings from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 on VS2017?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I've been searching (googling) on how to update my `asp.net mvc` scaffolding's from BS-3 to BS-4 !!
i try to update from `nuget` but it only updates bootstrap files scaffolding remains same for bootstrap 3.

> I found an answer on stack-overflow but it was for `asp.net core` and following those steps doesn't Solve my problem!

any Help Would be appreciated!
Latest Updated: `VS-2017`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you make visual studio scaffold etc. with bootstrap 4 in .NET MVC templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547452/can-you-make-visual-studio-scaffold-etc-with-bootstrap-4-in-net-mvc-templates)

Comment: @Erik Philips: but the answer in that question was for asp.net core as i've seen same answer before. Is it going to work in my case too?

Answer (score 0):

An update is not yet available from Microsoft, but at this link [Update Visual Studio 2017 MVC View Scaffolding to Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639302/update-visual-studio-2017-mvc-view-scaffolding-to-bootstrap-4/54851184#54851184) you can find how to update yourself the template for the Edit View used when scaffolding with Bootstrap 4

Comment: .net core 2.2 is officially updated to bootstrap 4 now. But haven't found for mvc. Ill sure look that link.