# bootstrap installation in visual studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I am using the latest visualstudio that comes with an older version of bootstrap 3 (when I choose the application template).
I tried to manually copy the lib files in the root folder of the new bootstrap 4 and the intellisense does not recognize it. Also the styles are not applied.
I tried installing the bootstrap package 4 (but it says incompatible) but nothing happen.
Which are the steps to have a fully working version of the new bootstrap on VS?

Comment: will this help? https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/making-beautiful-style-together-visual-studio-and-bootstrap.html

Answer (score 0):

There's an older question on StackOverflow which could contain the answer to your question.
If you didn't do already, give it a try: [Can you make visual studio scaffold etc. with bootstrap 4 in .NET MVC templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547452/can-you-make-visual-studio-scaffold-etc-with-bootstrap-4-in-net-mvc-templates)

Comment: What if you try to install it from NuGet?

Comment: When I tried that (no matter from the console or form the dialog) an item will appear in my nuget node in the solution explorer, but the lib files for bootstrap and jquery are not created and nothing happens